# Update progress bar from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, progress-bar

I have a really long `submit()`-type function on one of my web pages that runs entirely on the server, and I'd like to display a progress bar to the client to show the, well, progress.

I'd be ok with updating it at intervals of like `20%` so long as I can show them something.

Is this even possible? Maybe some kind of control with `runat="server"`? I'm kind of lost for ideas here.

Comment: Possible, yes, simple no.  It's *much* harder than in a desktop based environment.

Comment: @Servy Somehow I figured. Know of a good place to start?

Comment: The only way I can think of at the moment is that your long submit method would have to be converted to an ajax call. Then you'd have another ajax call that pings the server and returns the percent complete while the process is going on, which then updates whatever control you want on the page.

Comment: @DaveZych That's what I thought of at first, but unfortunately the method relies a lot on session (Dont look at me, I didn't write it :P )

Comment: I just finished writing up an answer.  In short, you're both right.  You'll need to do a lot of client polling the server, and storing progress in some sort of server side state (i.e. session).

Answer (score 4):

It's *possible*, but it's quite a bit harder to do in a web based environment than in, for example, a desktop based environment.

What you'll have to do is submit a request to the server, have the server start the async task and then send a response back to the client.  The client will then need to periodically poll the server (likely/ideally using AJAX) for updates.  The server will want to, within the long running task's body, set a Session value (or use some other method of storing state) that can be accessed by the client's polling method.

It's nasty, and messy, and inefficient, so you wouldn't want to do this if there are going to be lots of users executing this.

[Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETBackgroundWorker-dda8d7b6/view/SourceCode) is an example implementation by Microsoft.  Note that this example uses `UpdatePanel` objects, ASP timers, etc. which make the code quite a bit simpler to write (and it's still not all that pretty) but these components are fairly "heavy".  Using explicity AJAX calls, creating web methods rather than doing full postbacks, etc. will improve the performance quite a bit.  As I said though, even in the best of cases, it's a performance nightmare.  Don't do this if you have a lot of users or if this is an operation performed very much.  If it's just for occasional use by a small percentage of admin users then that may not be a concern, and it *does* add a lot from the user's perspective.

Comment: Can I access session from the ajax thread though? I haven't tried it, but it seems like it'd be in a different context

Comment: Yes, you can. `System.HttpContext.Current.Session`

Comment: Handling ajax requests in an ASP.NET application is no different from page requests in terms of having access to HttpContext, Session etc. Background thread, however, will have no access to Session, so storing progress counter in Session is out of the question, but the general idea of progress indicator in ASP.NET is well described in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at .net 4.5's async and await.

[Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) -- (MVC example I know sorry)

[Then check out this example using a progress bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708746.aspx)